# Wordpress error after database import

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have working WP website on server, I downloaded all files on local server to develop site, exported .sql file from phpmyadmin and imported on local phpmyadmin as well, suddenly receive this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in path/to/file/homepage.php on line 173

```
section class="news">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>most popular</h3>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">

        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sg-sidebar') ) : endif; ?>
        <?php // get_sidebar(); ?>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: provide full code from `homepage.php` file. we can't guess. what is metter for error

Comment: It could be the `if (...): endif;` line causing issues. If you're not executing anything based on the `if()` statement, try removing the whole line.

Comment: look at this line `<?php // get_sidebar(); ?>`. you commented php close tag `?>`. it cause the problem

Comment: i removed that line, did not help

Comment: ok, and remove this line, too `<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sg-sidebar') ) : endif; ?>` . it's nothing added, change.